# I am not seeing any content within WordPress after migration?

Tags: content

Last night I migrated a site to a live server using Duplicator, all seemed to work well. Today I just noticed that once logged in, WordPress is not displaying any content on the editor? Although the content is displaying on the front end?

Any suggestions would be gratefully received...

[image]

Comment: Are you able to highlight (seemingly) invisible text in the editor? I've seen cases on a Mac where a user style was being applied that hides the text in the Wordpress editor...

Comment: No, the content area is emtpy

Comment: Check your console for errors and examine the textarea/editor div to see if the content is missing or just hidden.

Comment: Yes, checked that, empty

Comment: In the above, you're using the "Text" tab. Is the "Visual" tab also blank/empty? (I'd assume so, but I want to be sure.)

Comment: Yes visual is also empty. I have gone through and re-inserted the content now. Luckily I still had it all on localhost. Very weird issue though

Answer (score 0):

Last time something like this happened to me it was because there were funky characters in the post content (which came, I think, from a database encoding difference between the source and destination databases). Anyway, that's where I'd look first. Use phpMyAdmin (or your favorite db tool) to check the `post_content` column of your `wp_posts` table for the unexpected.